What do these definitions have to do with random variables?
(This is a full rewrite of the original question I asked. The original was very poorly phrased - I'm hoping this rewrite gets at the central question more directly.)
(Take two of the rewrite because I am bad at expressing myself.)
A random variable is defined as a map $X : \Omega \to E$ from a sample space $\Omega$ to a measurable space $E$. I mostly get the concrete definition. But I'm really struggling to understand how random variables are related to the ways they get used.
For instance, the textbook I'm referencing (All Of Statistics) has a section titled "Some Important Continuous Random Variables", with entries like

The Uniform Distribution: $X$ has a $\text{Uniform}(a,b)$ distribution, written $X \sim \text{Uniform}(a,b)$, if
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{b-a} & \text{for } x \in [a,b]\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

I don't see the connection to random variables. Isn't this just defining a distribution where the sample space is $\mathbb{R}$?
Or take the cumulative distribution function. The book describes

Given a random variable $X$, we define the cumulative distribution function (or distribution function) as follows.
2.5 Definition. The cumulative distribution function, or CDF, is the function $F_X:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ defined by
$$F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq x).$$

Why does this definition invoke the concept of a random variable? I see $X$ getting used to define a particular event, namely $X \leq x$, but that's just an event. We can define events without resorting to measurable maps. It seems like we are again just talking about a specific feature of probability spaces over $\mathbb{R}$.
Or how about the definition of expected value

The mean, or expectation, of a random variable $X$ is the average value of $X$.
3.1 Definition. The expected value, or mean, or first moment, of $X$ is defined to be
$$\mathbb{E}(X) = \int x dF(x) = \begin{cases}\sum_x xf(x) & \text{if } X \text{ is discrete}\\\int xf(x)dx&\text{if } X \text{ is continuous}\end{cases}$$

Again, this seems intuitively to me like a property shared by any distribution over the real numbers. What has this got to do with random variables?
There is a common thread here. A number of things defined over random variables seem like they don't have anything to do with random variables. A lot of the times I see the words "random variable" all I'm greeted with is something that looks to me like a probability distribution over $\mathbb{R}$. I can see how you could use a random variable with range $\mathbb{R}$ to obtain a distribution over the reals from some other distribution. All these statements certainly apply to such an induced distribution. But it seems these statements apply to any distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, regardless of whether we got it by passing through a random variable or by directly defining the distribution manually.
What am I missing? Is there a reason we have to invoke the concept of a random variable for all these definitions? What parts of the definitions fail if we are only talking about a distribution over $\mathbb{R}$?

(Edit, one more try at explaining my question)
For an even more concrete example of what I'm talking about, suppose I define a distribution $D$ in the following way. I take the sample space to be $\mathbb{R}$. We use standard Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ to determine the class of events. And we define probability measure $P$ on the space of events by
$$P(E) = \begin{cases}1 & 1 \in E \\ 0 & \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$
I believe everything up until this point is standard. And I haven't used and RVs to define this distribution $D$.
Nevertheless it seems to me that, by virtue of $D$ being defined over a sample space $R$, it has a sensible notion of expectation. In particular the expected value for $D$ is 0. Likewise it has a sensible notion of CDF. In particular it is the Heaviside step function.
Perhaps the use of expectation and CDF are confusing here, so I'll call these expectation' and CDF'. The same concepts, but defined without reference to random variables and instead applying to all distributions over the reals.
Are expectation' and CDF' mathematically coherent? I think they are nonstandard, but is there a reason we couldn't define expectation' and CDF' in such a way that my analysis here makes sense? Or am I implicitly invoking something about RVs without noticing?

Real-valued random variables map into the reals, but the image of a random variable doesn't need to be a set of numbers at all.

Projections have a lot of applications, but why limit random variables to projections?

@Galen I'm a way outside my expertise, but a RV always maps into a measurable set, right? I was using the reals as an example of measurable set because that is how the textbook I'm using defines random variable, but if you'd like you could substitute "measurable set" in the place of "reals" and "random measurement" for "random number" and "measurable projection" for "numeric projection".

Also re:projections I might be using nonsense terminology. I don't mean projection in any formal sense, just in the sense that a random variable "projects" a distribution on some sample space into a distribution on a measurable space.

Fair enough. I do recommend using formal definitions. It greatly clarifies communication. Perhaps what you're referring to as projection is the notion of a pushforward measure.

Have you reviewed our thread on what random variables are?  Our threads about LOTUS also look relevant.  BTW, you seem to have the concept of measurability backwards: a measurable function is one whose inverse image of any measurable set is measurable.

@Galen Ok yeah good point. What I mean in formal terms by a "projection" is a random variable. A map $\Omega \to E$ where $E$ is measurable. The source of my confusion is that we seem to use random variables both as this map for inducing a measure on an existing space and as a way to talk about distributions on measurable spaces themselves. It is this second case that confuses me - why don't we study distributions on measurable sample spaces on their own, regardless of whether the measure is induced by a map or defined in some other way?

@whuber I did read that thread. I remember your answer - it's very good and whatever clarity about RVs I have is in part thanks to your answer there.
I'm still clumsy with the terminology, but I feel like I have some concept of measurability and what a measurable function means. The idea is that a measurable function is a function that can be used to induce a measure on a set, namely on the preimage of the measurable function. In this sense a measurable function is one of several ways to provide a measure to a set. This is my current understanding, lemme know if I'm wildly off.

Any function that could serve as a random variable determines a sigma algebra for its domain, but it does not determine either a probability measure or a distribution.  Conversely, a probability measure on a measure space does not determine a unique random variable, either. Thus it's conceptually useful to keep separate the concepts of a probability space, a random variable, and a distribution, especially because they are closely inter-related.

Yeah I think this is where I'm confused. I see the value of keeping these concepts distinct. But when we are talking about expectation or variance or defining the CDF my understanding is that all that matters is that $\Omega$ is measurable. Most properties we care about with measurable distributions don't change if we got measurability by an RV or by directly defining the measure ourselves. But the definitions I've seen for e.g. expectation explicitly mention that it is defined over RVs. Wouldn't defining expectation in terms of measurable distributions be both more general and simpler?

Actually I think I just need to update the question. The original was poorly phrased and I've got a better sense for what I really wanted to ask now. Thanks for helping me work through a couple ideas.

Your "measured distribution" seems to be what everyone else calls a "probability measure." I struggled to make sense of the ensuing material, but just could not succeed with it by the time "$M\le x$" appeared.  What is your mathematical definition of a "distribution" $M$??

Hmm okay yeah I thought that might be a more coherent idea. What I was thinking of as a "measured distribution" is a distribution with underlying sample space such that features like expected value and variance and CDF of the distribution make sense. The prototypical example being $\mathbb{R}$, but $\mathbb{N}$ and finite sets seem like they'd fit the bill too. I was under the impression that what made definitions of expected value et cetera make sense was that we were using RVs to map from a sample space with no structure to a sample space with a measure, but perhaps that's crazy talk.

Ok yeah I'm terribly confused about what a random variable is really used for. I mistook the idea that a RV maps to a measurable space to mean that there is some relation between measurable spaces and things like expected value. I thought that EV was defined for any RV, but this question has got me questioning that. Do measurable spaces and random variables have anything to do with CDFs, expected value, variance, etc or is it only that real-valued-RVs are very common and all this stuff is just defined for distributions over $\mathbb{R}$?

What makes EV work is that the values of a random variable lie in a space of mathematical objects that can be averaged, which requires that they can be scaled by probabilities and added: that more or less forces them to be in some kind of real vector space. I suspect a careful review of definitions would help you unravel these relationships and understand the concepts.

Your question lacks focus.  But--briefly--what unites the three examples is that they provide properties of a random variable $X.$  Notice that in all three cases one starts with $X$.  Each case goes on to describe or define a useful property.

But like where is the fact that $X$ is an RV being used? For instance the definition of CDF seems to only use the fact that a) we have a probability space and b) the underlying sample space $\Omega$ has a total ordering. I get that we could get our probability space by using a random variable to induce a probability space on a totally ordered set but is this definition coherent without doing this too? Is this definition intrinsically about random variables or is it a specific example of a more general statement, and we just work with RVs enough to not worry about the more general case?

Gandering at the comments and your post, there seems to be a huge set of confusion and misleading usage of terms like "measurable distributions don't change...", "$\Omega$ is measurable" (which, while not wrong, isn't used in correct context) etc. Two comments, particularly, by whuber and Galen should have provided the necessary insight.
Nevertheless, let us go back and see formally what the definitions are.
Let $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A}, \mathbf P)$ be a probability space. Let $(\Omega^\prime, \boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A^\prime}) $ be another measure space. A measurable map $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ is a random element; it is when $(\Omega^\prime, \boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A^\prime}) = (\mathbb R, \boldsymbol{ \mathfrak B}_\mathbb R), $ we call $X$ a random variable. It is this later space, the whole discussion revolves around and the underlying probability space $(\Omega, \boldsymbol{ \mathfrak A}) $ isn't of considerable interest (but not at all irrelevant).
The cumulative distribution function is defined based on the  probability measure induced by the random variable $X, $ that is,
$$\mathrm F_X(x) :=\mathbf P_X((-\infty,x])=\mathbf P(X^{-1}(-\infty,x]),~~\forall x\in\mathbb R;$$
here $\mathbf P_X$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure determined by $\mathrm F_X$ on $\mathbb R, $ namely $\mu_{\mathrm F_X}$ (cf. $\rm[I, ~Def. 22.5]$).
Now assume $\mathrm F_X$ is absolutely continuous on $\mathbb R. $ Then $\mu_{\mathrm F_X}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ on $\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak B}_\mathbb R $ (cf. $\rm[I, ~Th. 22.21]$) and the corresponding RN derivative is ${\mathrm F^\prime_X}=: f_X, $ the density of the random variable $X$ (cf. $\rm[I, ~Th. 22.22]$).
Expectation of a real-valued $\boldsymbol{ \mathfrak B}_\mathbb R$–measurable function $g$ of random variable $X$ is defined by $$\mathbf E[g\circ X]:=\int_\Omega (g\circ X) (\omega) ~\mathbf P(\mathrm d\omega) ;$$ by integration of image measure (cf. $\rm[I, ~Th.~9.34]$), we have
$$\begin{align}\mathbf E[g\circ X]&=\int_\mathbb R g (y) ~\mathbf P_X(\mathrm dy)\\&=\int_\mathbb R g (y) ~\mu_{\mathrm F_X}(\mathrm dy)\\&=: \int_\mathbb R g (y) ~\mathrm F_X(\mathrm dy)\tag 1\label 1,\end{align}$$ which is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral of $g$ with respect to $\mathrm F_X.$
By the assumption of absolute continuity of $\mathrm F_X$ on $\mathbb R, $  we can write $\eqref 1$ as (cf. $\rm[I, ~Prop. 22.23]$)
\begin{align}\mathbf E[g\circ X]=\int_\mathbb R g (y) f_X(y) ~\lambda(\mathrm dy).\tag 2\end{align}
The random variable $X$ dictates what its expectation would be and its other properties, via the induced probability measure $\mathbf P_X.$
--
Reference:
$\rm [I]$ Real Analysis: Theory of Measure and Integration, J. Yeh, World Scientific, $2014.$

Ok so if I'm getting you we might have our underlying space $(\Omega,\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A},\mathbf P)$ and a random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. Using $X$ we can induce a distribution on $R$ from the underlying space to get a new space $(\mathbb{R},\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A'},\mathbf P_X)$. It is over this new space where expectation and CDF and so on are defined. But why go through an RV at all? Wouldn't EV and CDF etc be defined for any $(\mathbb{R},\boldsymbol{\mathfrak A'},\mathbf P)$, regardless of how $\mathbf P$ was generated?

EV (I am assuming it stands for expected value) and cdf are defined for random variable and not a probability space. The former is the integral of a measurable function $\int_\Omega X(\omega) ~\mathbf P(\mathrm d\omega) $ while cdf is defined in terms of the push forward measure $\mathbf P_X$ (note carefully the former is defined on the underlying probability space and the latter is defined on the space $X$ takes values on).

Sorry, I realize I'm being unclear. I get that CDF and expectation are defined on random variables. I'm wondering if you could define similar concepts for distributions themselves? For example it seems like we could compute something quite a lot like the CDF for any distribution $D$ over $R$ using $F_D(x) := \mathbf P_D((-\infty,x])$. This is clearly not the CDF because it has nothing to say about RVs, but it seems quite similar to the CDF. Am I implicitly using RVs without realizing it? Or perhaps this isn't well defined? Or is my pseudo-CDF fully acceptable mathematically, just irrelevant?

Exactly. You answered it yourself. You are implicitly using a random variable $X\sim D. $

Ahh ok this is breaking my brain. If you were to be explicit about where I'm using $X$ in my weird pseudo-CDF, where is it? Because I'm totally missing it. Stepping through it, on the left we have $F_D(x)$. The RV isn't used here because I'm just naming a function. Then we have the event $(-\infty, x]$. Events are standard for distributions, so I don't think I need an RV to make this event. Last I'm evaluating $P_D$ at the event. Once again this is standard for any event for any distribution. But that's all there is to the expression! What did I miss? Where was the measurable map hidden?

Let $D:=\mathcal N_{\mu,\sigma^2}.$ Then $\mathbf P_X:= \mathcal N_{\mu,\sigma^2} =  \phi\lambda$ where $\phi$ is the normal density. $\mathrm F_D =\mathrm F_X$ is still given by $\mathbf P(X^{-1}((-\infty, x]) $ but now we have the form. So, we can write $\mathrm F_X(x) =\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t) ~\mathrm dt. $This is owing to the fact that $\mathbf P_X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda.$ Random variable never got out of the picture. It dictates what its properties are.

Sanity check: when you are using $X$ in this example, we don't really know anything about nor do we care about the preimage of $X$, except that when the underlying sample space passes through $X$ we find a normal distribution. $X$ is effectively using the underlying probability space to generate a new probability space where the sample space is $\mathbb R$, and it is because we have this induced probability space that we can make sense of the CDF as you describe it above. Is my understanding close to right?

It could have been more accurately framed. But yes, at least unlike your other confusions, that is indeed a good start.

Perhaps take a pause. Read again. Ponder over it. At least, you are unfolding things in the right direction.
